# How to deploy EAR file in WebSphre clustered environment?

Tags: websphere

Can any one explain how to deploy EAR file in clustered environment of WebSphere 7.
I'm able to deploy the same in single node but not in clustered environment

Answer (score 1):

You deploy the EAR to the cluster and WebSphere 7 deploys the EAR to the systems that make up the cluster.

Here are some instructions for deploying your application on WebSphere Application Server 7.0

[Part 1](http://www.packtpub.com/article/deploying-applications-on-websphere-application-server-7.0-part1)

[Part 2](http://www.packtpub.com/article/deploying-applications-on-websphere-application-server-7.0-part2)