# About Java Bean

Tags: java, class, javabeans, abstract

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a Java Bean exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295496/what-is-a-java-bean-exactly)

This is a simple question about Java Bean, there is some restriction in the type of classe? For example, a bean can be a abstract class ?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html

Answer (score 8):

A JavaBean class is a class which respects a number of conventions. But depending on the usage of the class, some conventions are or aren't important. In the strict sense, a JavaBean class

- must have a public no-arg constructor allowing to instantiate it
- must have properties available through getters and setters
- must be serializable

So, in the strict sense, a JavaBean class may not be abstract. But an abstract class can be the superclass of a JavaBean class.

Comment: Good edit. I was just about to point that out.