# Java initialize class in style like in C#

Tags: java, c#, class, initialization, code-cleanup

I'm quite base in Java because I'm full time C# developer but i need make some private project in Android.

In C# i can do something like this :

```
public class Test
{
    public string A {get;set;}
    public OtherClass B {get;set;}
}

public OtherClass ()
{
    string Some {get;set;}
    string Again {get;set;}
}
```

Now when I want to use class test i can do code like:

```
var test = new Test
{
    A = "test",
    B = new OtherClass
    {
        Some = "Some",
        Again = "Again"
    }
};
```

Thank to this now i have initialized test in clear way.

When i want do this in Java i must make code like :

```
public class Test
{
    private string A;
    public string GetA()
    {
        return A;
    }
    public void SetA(string a)
    {
        A = a;
    }

    privte  OtherClass B;
    public OtherClass GetB()
    {
        return B;
    }
    public void SetB(OtherClass b)
    {
        B = b;
    }
}



public class OtherClass
{
    private string Some;
    public string GetSome()
    {
        return Some;
    }
    public void SetSome(string some)
    {
        Some = some;
    }

    privte  string Again;
    public string GetAgain()
    {
        return Again;
    }
    public void SetAgain(string again)
    {
        Again = again;
    }
}
```

I know that Java must have Seter and Geter to field and i'm ok with this but now if i want to use `Test` object in way like i use it in C# i must do something like :

```
OtherClass otherClass = new OtherClass();
otherClass.SetSome("Some");
otherClass.SetAnothier("Another");
Test test = new Test();
test.SetA("A")
test.SetB(otherClass);
```

IMO this is not nice and clear declaration. I know that i can add constructor like :

```
public Test(string a, otherClass b)
{
    A = a;
    B = b;
}
```

and

```
public OtherClass(string some,string another)
{
     Some = some;
     Another = another;
}
```

And use it like :

```
Test test = new Test("Test",new OtherClass("some","Another"));
```

But when i have more complicated classes ( e.g with 200 field ( yes i have that )) the constructor will be very long and it will hard to read it.

So can I initialize class in Java in other way that this I show you ?

Thank

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can actually use `object initializers` in java also, however they are called `double brace initializers`. Example:

```
Test test = new Test()
{{
    SetA("test");
    SetB(new OtherClass()
    {{
        SetSome("Some");
        SetAgain("Again");
    }});
}};
```

However you should probably not use this since it has some weird/unexpected side effects. This example produces an `AnonymousInnerClass` for `Test` and `OtherClass`. You can read more about double brace initializers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958636/what-is-double-brace-initialization-in-java).

If you have more parameters than you wish to pass down your constructor you could use the builder pattern as suggested [by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9108655/3177092).

Comment: It look like that was I looking for. Those double brace scare me a little bit because amount of brace can make find bug even worse especial when will initialize object in some function :) But this look perfect to me. It is taking less resource than method hat i show in my post ?

Comment: It takes much more resource - every object you create like this has its own class.

Comment: That's actually a misuse of anonymous inner classes - made popular by people who really really want Java to look like C#.

Comment: @Aht: The main concern should not be a cosmetic concern - your main concern should be "is the code doing what needs to be done" - in this case there's this hidden class instantiation going on that has no business happening here.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas: So i will remember that solution but i will try to avoid it