# What does "The type ArrayList is not generic" mean?

Tags: java

I am new to Java and trying to learn the various collections that programmers can use. I imported "java.util" into a scrapbook in Eclipse and inspected the following code.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("test1");
list.add("test2");
```

I receive this output.

```
The type ArrayList is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String>
Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 5.0
The type ArrayList is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String>
Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 5.0
```

What does this error mean? I did not make a generic array list; I made an array list of strings. Furthermore, what is "source level"?

Comment: You have java version less than 5.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your Java version in Eclipse is set to 1.4, generics in java were introduced only in Java 5.

Change your JDK to 1.5 or above in eclipse that will resolve this issue.

You can check your JDK by `Project - > Java Build Path - > Libraries`

If here you see it being Java 1.5 or above then check the compiler Compliance is set to 5 and above.

You can check that `Project - > Java Compiler`

EDIT:

To add new jdk to Eclipse

Right click on **Project - > Java Build Path - > Libraries - > Add Libraries - > JRE System Library - > Installed Libraries - > Add - > Standard VM - > Provide your installation location and press OK**

*Note in the list of Installed JRE, ensure that you check your Java 7.*

Comment: Thank you! I have downloaded and installed JDK 7 from Oracle. I am wondering how to tell Eclipse to use that JDK though.

Comment: Thank you! Adding a new JRE System library as you noted in the edit above and then changing my source level in Project -> Properties -> Java Compiler to 6.0 worked.

Answer (score 4):

What comes into my mind:

- check if the JDK is fully compliant with generics (so that the `ArrayList` class in your JSE is actually a generic class)
- check if you don't have another `ArrayList` which has scope precedence and overrides the standard library definition

Comment: I had to remove org.osgi.foundation-1.2.0.jar from the build path to fix the problem. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the problem goes away for 1.5 and above. It feels like the question is not completely addressed though, I'm adding my 2 cents in case anybody comes across this question. It's mainly about this part of the question:

> I did not make a generic array list; I made an array list of strings.

The error message mentioned:

> > The type ArrayList is not *generic*; it cannot be *parameterized* with arguments <String>
>
> > Syntax error, *parameterized types* are only available if source level is 5.0

What it actually means is, since Java 1.5 we can use Type parameters also (where in one was used to using value parameters). JDK 1.5 introduces *generics*, which allows us to abstract over types (or **parameterized types**).

The class designers can be *generic* about types in the definition. The arrayList implementation would be as below:

```
public class ArrayList<E> implements List<E> .... {
    // Constructor
    public ArrayList() {...}

    // Public methods
    public boolean add(E e) {...}
    public void add(int index, E element) {...}
    public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends E> c) {...}
    public abstract E get(int index) {...}
    public E remove(int index) {...}
    ...
}
```

Where **E** can be *any* type like String or Integer etc. Hence the name **generic** arrayList.

The users can be specific in the types during the object instantiation or method invocation which was done in this example like below:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

(Which was the confusion in above case, if I am not wrong :-))

Example of the usage of generics (if needed):

```
// Declaring a DAO layer
public interface IMasterAbstractDao<E, I> {
    public E findById(I id) {...}
    public void delete(E e) {...}
    public List<E> findByCriteria(Criterion criterion) {...}
}
```

Where **E** is the entity type returned. This can be used for all the Model [beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295496/what-is-a-javabean-exactly) defined in the system making it generic.

Hope this helps.

[Reference: Java Programming Tutorial - Generics](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaGeneric.html)