# ArrayList is not generic; cannot be parameterized

Tags: java, arraylist

So I'm trying to create an ArrayList of the type Item which is an Object of the Item class that I have defined in a separate file. This is the code I have pertaining to the issue:

```
import java.util.ArrayList; 
private ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

The error that I am receiving is this:

```
The type ArrayList is not generic; it cannot be paramaterized with arguments <Item>
```

I have a different file for another program in which I have declared and used an ArrayList of and Object and it worked fine.

I'm fairly new to Java so if this is a rookie mistake I'm sorry. What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: Do you have your own class named `ArrayList`? Try `private java.util.List<Item> items = new java.util.ArrayList<Item>();`

Comment: The latest version of Java, Update 7.51. I'm using Eclipse.

Comment: Where is the `Item` class in relation to the class where you are making this declaration?

Comment: The Item class is in the same directory as this file.

Comment: As suggested, please try `List<Item> = new ArrayList<Item>();`

Comment: @ElliotFrisch I tried that and it still comes up with the same error but List instead of ArrayList.

Comment: Also, make sure your java code level is set correctly in Eclipse. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557102/what-does-the-type-arraylist-is-not-generic-mean

Comment: Please show the whole code, not just a snippet.

Comment: @ZacharyD I will post this as an anwer, please mark it as such. You are welcome :)

Comment: And thank you to everyone else for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your java code level is set correctly in Eclipse. Look here for instruction how to check/change it: [What does "The type ArrayList is not generic" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557102/what-does-the-type-arraylist-is-not-generic-mean)

To summarize:
1. Right-click on your project and go to `Properties`, then to `Java Compiler`
2. Make sure your Compiler Compliance level is at least 1.5 as that's when generics were introduced.

Comment: It would be good to briefly summarize (or even quote) the answer in the other question, in the event that the other question is deleted and this one remains.

Comment: @turbo you are right, I added a summary.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had a similar problem few days back the problem is that there are two different libraries in your classpath with same class name and package structure this sometimes happen. To solve this try removing all the libraries from your project and see if this works.

It worked for me so it should work for you as well. If it works then you have to order the export of libraries in eclipse and make JRE libraries to be higher than the other libraries