# "The type ArrayList is not generic" with Eclipse 4.4.2 and Java 1.8 compiler

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, arraylist

With this small piece of code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class testClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

}
```

I get Eclipse warning:

The type ArrayList is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments

I saw in other post ([What does "The type ArrayList is not generic" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557102/what-does-the-type-arraylist-is-not-generic-mean)) things related to wrong java version being selected for Eclipse, but for me I have the 1.8 version selected for execution:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3kaklvx00dmeff4/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-06%20at%2007.51.39.png?dl=0

I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. Any tips?

Comment: Your screen capture reveals you are compiling using Java 1.8.  But can you verify what version of the JDK you are using to **execute**?

Comment: Have you enabled any project specific settings? please check JRE version displayed in your project.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen From the run configurations: https://www.dropbox.com/s/89pazqfrzvpqtge/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-06%20at%2008.08.34.png?dl=0

Satty: I have checked those and across the board it says 1.8 version.

How ever, I just now managed to make it work by removing the "import java.util.*" from the top and replacing it with "import java.util.List" and "import java.util.ArrayList". Why isn't the wildcard import working?

Comment: It could be that eclipse got itself into a bad state.  Put the * back and see if it breaks it again.

Comment: I just built your program using JDK 8 on the command line and there were no warnings.  It seems likely that the problem is something to do with Eclipse here.

Comment: Adding the wildcard back in, breaks the code again :)

Comment: And what does closing and reopening eclipse do?

Comment: Can you clean the project. Project > Clean

Comment: Restarted eclipse -> no go.
Cleaned the Project and restarted eclipse again -> no go.

Comment: You may have found a bug.  If you can describe how reproduce it go here and report it if it hasn't already been reported: https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_report_a_bug_in_Eclipse%3F

Comment: [PEBKAC](https://xkcd.com/1031/)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Did not quite get your point?

EDIT: Ah, now after edit I see your point :)
Yeah, this can be closed. The original question is indeed a duplicate and the description etc does not match the side trailing discussion here. I shall open a new question if I cannot resolve this through the eclipse groups.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you make your own class named `ArrayList` which hides the standard `java.util.ArrayList`?

Comment: ... This was exactly it :D I completely forgot that I had created the ArrayList named class for the project. Thanks for pointing out that :D

Comment: so, in the end, this wasn't a duplicate after all I guess. I mean, the question text currently is, but with extra information this would be different.