# AbstractListModel is not generic with jdk 1.6.0_45

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, maven, generics

I'd like to define a Swing combobox model as follows:

```
public class SchemaGroupModel<E> extends AbstractListModel<E> implements ComboBoxModel<E>
```

but Eclipse raises the error (twice):

```
The type AbstractListModel is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <E>
```

I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) (raw type definition), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557102/what-does-the-type-arraylist-is-not-generic-mean) (old JDKs) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804287/the-type-collection-is-not-generic-it-cannot-be-parameterized-with-arguments) (position of JDK library in the Java Build path). From these replies I guess that the problem should be the version of the JDK or its position in the IDE's libraries. But I doubled checked: I'm using **JDK 1.6** and such library comes *before* Maven dependencies.

[Eclipse's screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZFcU.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This class wasn't generic in Java 6

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractListModel.html

```
public abstract class AbstractListModel
extends Object
implements ListModel, Serializable
```

you can see that in Java 7 it was made generic.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractListModel.html

```
public abstract class AbstractListModel<E>
extends Object
implements ListModel<E>, Serializable
```

however, if you are going to update, I suggest using Java 8 as Java 7 is EOL.

Comment: Thank you very much. 
I've been misleaded by the (mentioned) answers to similar problems, which suggested to move to version 1.6. Unfortunately I must stay to Java 6 (customer requirements), so I will avoid generics in this case

Comment: @serkelion today a fixed a client reported bug which only shows up in Java 8 update 74 but not update 66. A good problem to have I suppose. ;)

Comment: Yes, but this is just the tip of the iceberg. ;)