# Netbeans - Swing Binding

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I'm using NetBeans IDE 7.2 on Windows 7 to create a Java Swing Application.

I'm using this IDE since about one month, therefore I have explored many of its features. But there is a particular one -- called *binding* / *bind* -- which I don't know what it does.

This can be found at the *project* tab, which is showed when you create a Java Swing source code (for example, with the `File > New Project`). Adding any object (like a JSpinner for e.g.) to the JFrame, and right clicking on it, there it is: the *vinculate* option.

So, does anybody know what is the purpose / utility of "binding"?

Comment: Did you try the NetBeans help?

Comment: Nope, don't see it.  Sure you haven't got any plugins installed?

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but did you configure NetBeans to use a language other than English (if it is even possible)?

Comment: I googled for netbeans and vinculate and came up with a couple of references. Apparently, vinculate means 'bind' When I click on a component on a form, the second option is 'bind' Is it the second option? What version of Netbeans? What language is your computer/netbeans configured for?

Comment: You are right people, I made a mistake. I'm using the portuguese version, whose word stands for "vincular/vinculação", and I made the most straigthforward / obvious translation to english, becoming "vinculation". This explains why I didn't find anything relevant at Google before. I think the correct translation is just "bind". This option is near the 'events', you can check [here](http://goo.gl/IM4Im). Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've googled a little and found the following:

http://www.formdev.com/jformdesigner/doc/ui/beans-binding/

http://forums.netbeans.org/topic1651.html

Java Bean, related to binding:
[What is a JavaBean exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295496/what-is-a-java-bean-exactly)

Basically, binding is a property with the following: we have a source and a target, and we want to **bind** one target property (a text from JTextField, the selected state from a JCheckBox) with some source property (say, some int value, or some string text, or even one flag/boolean). The target usually is one Swing component, and the source can be either a Swing component too, or a custom Bean (maybe a Class, maybe not) created by the user.

One classic example is to **bind** a JSlider Value (source) with a JTextField (target).

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's described in [the Netbeans docs](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-binding.html).