# Why this propertyChange() method can't handle this event?

Tags: java, swing, events, event-handling, propertychangelistener

I am pretty new in **Swing** development and I have the following problem using a class that implements the **PropertyChangeListener** interface.

So I have the following **GUI** class (I am posting only the interesting section of this class):

```
public class GUI extends SingleFrameApplication implements PropertyChangeListener {

private MainFrame mainFrame = null;
private static LoginFrame loginFrame;

    @Override
protected void startup() {
    boolean offLine = false;
            showLoginFrame();

    mainFrame = new MainFrame(settings, tasksSettings, logAppender);

    if (OSUtils.isUbuntuPrecisePangolin() || OSUtils.isFedoraBeefyMiracle() || OSUtils.isFedoraSphericalCow()) {
        File mountPointFolder = new File(System.getenv("HOME") + "/connect_drives");
        if (!mountPointFolder.exists())
            mountPointFolder.mkdir();

        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                if (mainFrame.getState() == JFrame.ICONIFIED)
                    tryToExit();
                else
                    mainFrame.setState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);
            }
        });
    }
}

private void showLoginFrame() {
    loginFrame = new LoginFrame();
    loginFrame.setVisible(true);
    loginFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    // Notify every change to every bound property for that object:
    loginFrame.addPropertyChangeListener(this); 

}

@Override
protected void shutdown() {
    System.out.println("Entered into GUI ---> shutdown()");
    logger.debug("Termino l'applicazione.");
    ulogger.info(Constants.APP_TITLE + "|Arresto "+ Constants.APP_TITLE);
    // FileUtils.saveGeneralLogFile(logAppender.getLogInFile());
    logAppender.saveGeneralLogFile();
    EventBusService.unsubscribe(this);
    if (mainFrame != null)
        mainFrame.setVisible(false);

}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    launch(GUI.class, args);
}

@Override
public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println("GUI SingleFrameApplication ---> propertyChange(): " + arg0.getPropertyName());

    if (arg0.getPropertyName().equals("buttonLogOffClicked")) {
        //System.out.println("GUI SingleFrameApplication ---> richiamo exit");
        //exit();

        mainFrame.OnWindowClose();
        mainFrame.dispose();
        mainFrame = null;

        showLoginFrame();
    }

    if (arg0.getPropertyName().equals("loginResult")) {
        System.out.println("GUI SingleFrameApplication ---> richiamo MainFrame");
        //loginFrame.setVisible(false);
        loginFrame.dispose();
        loginFrame = null;

        showMainFrame();
    }

}

private void showMainFrame() {

    mainFrame = new MainFrame(settings, tasksSettings, logAppender);
    // I add a PropertyChangeListener to the created MainFrame object:
    mainFrame.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    WindowListener exitListener = new WindowAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.out.println("GUI SingleFrameApplication --> windowClosing");
            shutdown();
            // mainFrame.setVisible(false);
            /*int confirm = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
            "Are You Sure to Close this Application?",
            "Exit Confirmation", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
            if (confirm == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            System.exit(1);
            }*/
        }
    };

    mainFrame.addWindowListener(exitListener);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Then I have the **MainFram** class that extends a **JFrame** in which there is a **JButton** to perform the log out operation, something like this:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    private final Action actionLogOut = new AbstractAction() {
        {
            putValue(Action.NAME, _("log-out"));
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("logOutButton clicked !!!, firePropertyChange() will start");
            // System.exit(0);
            firePropertyChange("buttonLogOffClicked", false, true);
        }
    };

    public MainFrame(Settings settings, TasksSettings tasksSettings, LogAppender logAppender) {
        super();
    ......................
    ......................
    ......................
    header.add(new JButton(actionLogOut));
    ......................
    ......................
    ......................
    }
}
```

So when my **JButton** is clicked it is performed this method:

```
private final Action actionLogOut = new AbstractAction() {
    {
        putValue(Action.NAME, _("log-out"));
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("logOutButton clicked !!!, firePropertyChange() will start");
        // System.exit(0);
        firePropertyChange("buttonLogOffClicked", false, true);
    }
};
```

infact when I click on the button, in the console, appear to me the output:

**"logOutButton clicked !!!, firePropertyChange() will start"**

and then I execute the **firePropertyChange()** method and I would expect that this event was handle by this method of **GUI** class:

```
@Override
public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println("GUI SingleFrameApplication ---> propertyChange(): " + arg0.getPropertyName());

    if (arg0.getPropertyName().equals("buttonLogOffClicked")) {
        //System.out.println("GUI SingleFrameApplication ---> richiamo exit");
        //exit();

        mainFrame.OnWindowClose();
        mainFrame.dispose();
        mainFrame = null;

        showLoginFrame();
    }

    if (arg0.getPropertyName().equals("loginResult")) {
        System.out.println("GUI SingleFrameApplication ---> richiamo MainFrame");
        //loginFrame.setVisible(false);
        loginFrame.dispose();
        loginFrame = null;

        showMainFrame();
    }

}
```

But don't work and seems not enter in the **firePropertyChange()** method?

Why? What am I missing?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: now really new, AFAIK did you post an SSCCE

Comment: It seams that [`PropertyChangeListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html) is for "*a component that conforms to the JavaBeans™ specification.*". So [`Property`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/properties.html) is used  in `JavaBean` context.

Comment: @PM77-1, and which things are java beans ?

Comment: @Sage : `JavaBean` is a Java class that adheres to a certain standard. I believe that the accepted answer in [What is a Java Bean exactly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295496/what-is-a-java-bean-exactly) post explains it well.  Are you saying that `JFrame` itself is a bean?

Comment: yes, Components are Beans too.

Comment: @Sage : But is `JButton` a *property* of `MainFrame`? So anything within a container is a property of a container?

Comment: @PM77-1, Nope, a component is not a property of another component. But Every component has their own property: bounds, preferredsize, minimumSize. And Every component has `getXXX()` and `setXXX()` method to get and set their property `xxx`. So we can fire an event on property change and have them listen to it:)

Comment: @Sage : So as long as we `fire` from **within** the class `listener` attached to, the rest doesn't matter, right?

Answer (score 1):

When you are calling `firePropertyChange` from the `MainFrame` context it is firing for the `MainFrame`, which can actually listen to it's property change event.  But instead you have added listener to the `login frame`, using `loginFrame.addPropertyChangeListener(this)`; `loginframe` will listen to the change, if a change event is fired by it's own `firePropertyChange` function. However you can call `loginFrame.firePropertyChange("buttonLogOffClicked", false, true)`; from the `actionPerformed()` function of `actionLogOut` Action, in `MainFrame` class.

**Edit:**

1. Try passing the instance of `LoginFrame` to `MainFrame` instance constructor, you have created to work with.
2. Or, In your GUI class declare a `static` function named like `fireLogInPropEvent`. You will need to declare your `LoginFrame` instance as static. Then inside this function put `loginFrame.firePropertyChange("buttonLogOffClicked", false, true)` to listen to this property.

   ```
   public class GUI extends SingleFrameApplication implements PropertyChangeListener {


       private MainFrame mainFrame = null;
       private static LoginFrame loginFrame = new LoginFrame();

       /// your other code

       private void showLoginFrame() {
           // loginFrame = new LoginFrame(); <------- already created hence commenting out
           loginFrame.setVisible(true);
           loginFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

           // Notify every change to every bound property for that object:
           loginFrame.addPropertyChangeListener(this); 

        }

         public static void fireLogInPropEvent()
         {
            loginFrame.firePropertyChange("buttonLogOffClicked", false, true);
         }

      }
   ```

Comment: mmm seems don't work, because in this class I have not a LoginFrame instance...what am I missing?

Comment: @AndreaNobili: as Sage is saying, what you're missing is that you seem to be adding your PropertyChangeListener to the *Wrong Object*. You need to add it to the correct object for the code to make sense and to work. 1+

Comment: @AndreaNobili, you have actually understood that, you will need an instance of `LoginFrame` in the `MainFrame` class to fire a property change event for `LoginFrame` from `MainFrame`. This type of hazard you will face, for using multiple frame in one application. I have said you many times before, and i am telling you now, change the design style. Make use of card layout and do things with one frame

Comment: I can't change the layout style...I am workikg on an old big application I have to mantein the original layout also if it is not so smart :(

Comment: @AndreaNobili, ok. Take a look at my edited answer. you should have got it working now with changes i have mentioned