# Difference between JavaBean and Spring bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, javabeans, spring-bean

I am new to Spring MVC and have a little idea of the usage of java beans in Java.
What is the basic difference between a Java bean and Spring bean?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-definition

Comment: They're completely different patterns. JavaBean: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3295496/139010

Comment: They are plain POJOs whose lyfecycle is maintained by a container. JavaBeans are managed by a Java *standard*(?) container e.g. JSF Managed Beans, EJBs, CDI beans... while Spring beans are managed by the Spring container.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

> ### JavaBeans:
>
> At a basic level, JavaBeans are simply Java classes which adhere to certain coding conventions. Specifically, classes that
>
> - have `public` default (no argument) constructors
> - allow access to their properties using accessor (getter and setter) methods
> - implement `java.io.Serializable`

> ### Spring Beans:
>
> A Spring bean is basically an object managed by Spring. More specifically, it is an object that is instantiated, configured and otherwise managed by a [Spring Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework) container. Spring beans are defined in Spring configuration files (or, more recently, with annotations), instantiated by Spring containers, and then injected into applications.

Note that Spring beans need not always be JavaBeans. Spring beans might not implement the `java.io.Serializable` interface, **can have arguments in their constructors**, etc.

This is the very basic difference between JavaBeans and Spring beans.

For more information, refer to the source of the above text, Shaun Abram's article [*JavaBeans vs Spring beans vs POJOs*](http://www.shaunabram.com/beans-vs-pojos/).

Answer (score 0):

**Spring Bean:**

A class which is developed as part of a spring application. Its life cycle which is managed by Spring Container is called as Spring Bean.

Comment: What does this answer add beyond the existing, accepted one?

Comment: Welcome to SO, kindly make sure before you post an answer at least look that thread for other positive score answers or accepted ones then decide if your amswer is adding something useful then its okay else refrain from posting it

Answer (score 0):

Java beans and Spring beans are more related than different.

For a Java class to be usable as a Java bean, its setter- and getter-method names [need](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/index.html) to be as per the JavaBean guidelines (also called design patterns) for [properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/properties.html). If such a Java class is instantiable & manageable by the Spring IoC container, it is a Spring bean. To achieve this, the programmer [wires](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-annotation-config) the class as a bean definition of a suitable [scope](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-scopes) by using XML config files or annotations or a mix of both. The programmer can create new Spring beans out of existing Spring beans by wiring further by passing the latter to constructor-arguments of the former either as string-names as `<idref>` elements or by dependency injection (it can be recursive).

This answer may be read in conjunction with my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295496/what-is-a-javabean-exactly/57821307#57821307) SO answer to get more background information.