# Java Spring Cannot Create Bean with Enums as Constructor Parameters

Tags: java, spring, enums, spring-framework-beans

I am new to Spring but I haven't found an answer to this after searching for over an hour.  I am making a simple deck of cards and I can't get my Card object to instantiate with two Enums as parameters in the constructor.  Are Enums possible with Spring?  Can I not hardwire in the config class? Here is my code:

```
@Component
public class Card {

    EnumValue value;
    EnumSuit suit;

    public Card(EnumValue v, EnumSuit s) {
        value = v;
        suit = s;

    }

    public EnumValue getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(EnumValue value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public EnumSuit getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    public void setSuit(EnumSuit suit) {
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("[%s][%s]", value.getShortName(), suit.getShortName());
    }
}

@Component
public enum EnumValue {
    ACE("A",1), TWO("2", 2), THREE("3", 3), FOUR("4", 4), FIVE("5", 5), SIX("6", 6), SEVEN("7", 7), 
    EIGHT("8", 8), NINE("9", 9), TEN("T", 10), JACK("J", 10), QUEEN("Q", 10), KING("K", 10);

    private String shortName;
    private int points;


    EnumValue(String name, int score){
        shortName = name;
        points = score;
    }


    public String getShortName() {
        return shortName;
    }


    public void setShortName(String shortName) {
        this.shortName = shortName;
    }


    public int getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    public void setPoints(int points) {
        this.points = points;
    }
}


@Component
public enum EnumSuit {
    CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES;

    public String getShortName() {
        return this.toString().substring(0,1);
    }
}


@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.betterstuff.learnspring")
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public Card getSampleCard() {
        return new Card(EnumValue.ACE, EnumSuit.CLUBS);
    }
}

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);

        Card obj = (Card) context.getBean(Card.class);

        System.out.println("My Card is: " + obj.toString());

    }

}
```

I am getting the error:

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'card' defined in file [...\Card.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com...EnumValue' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
Exception in thread "main" UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'card' defined in file [...\Card.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com...EnumValue' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Comment: `Card` cannot not be a Spring Bean, especially not a *singleton* bean. It is a Java Bean though, see [Difference between JavaBean and Spring bean](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21866571/5221149). --- Now, if you create a class `Deck`, it could potentially be a Spring Bean.

Answer (score 1):

Since you annotated `@Component` on `Card` class spring is trying to create bean during application context, and since you declared argument constructor there will no default constructor available

```
public Card(EnumValue v, EnumSuit s) {
    value = v;
    suit = s;

}
```

So remove the `@Component` from `Card` class, and also same mistake for `Enum` class `EnumValue`, either you can add default constructor or remove the `@Component`

```
EnumValue(){
 }
```