# my bean class is not been able to get identified by jsp engine

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

I am new to jsp and beans.I tried to make a small bean example but getting a jsp compile time error as follows:

```
Student.jsp:1:1: Needed class "find_record.StudentBean" is not found.
^
Student.jsp:4:34: The bean type "find_record.StudentBean" was not found.
<jsp:useBean id="findbean" class="find_record.StudentBean" scope="session" />
                             ^-----------------------^
Student.jsp:5:23: This bean name does not exist.
<jsp:setProperty name="findbean" property="rollno" />
```

i have a Student.jsp to call StudentBean.java but getting that error
following are the code:
Student.jsp

```
<html>
<body >
<jsp:useBean id="findbean" class="find_record.StudentBean" scope="session" />
<jsp:setProperty name="findbean" property="rollno" />
<%
 String status=findbean.findRecord();
  if(status.equals("success"));
%>
<jsp:include page="Success.jsp" />
<% else %>
<jsp:include page="Error.jsp" />

</body>
</html>
```

StudentBean.java

```
//StudentBean,java
package find_record;
import java.sql.*;
public class StudentBean{
String name ,rollno,grade;
int marks;
public StudentBean(){}
public void setName(String name){
     this.name=name;
     }
 public  void setRollno(String rollno){
     this.rollno=rollno;
     }
 public void setMarks(int marks){
      this.marks=marks;
     }

  public  void setGrade(String grade){
     this.grade=grade;
      }

   public String getName(){
       return(name);
      }
   public String getRollno(){
        return(rollno);
     }

    public int getMarks(){
         return(marks);
       }
    public String getGrade(){
       return(grade);
      }
     public String findRecord(){

    try{
          Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
  Connection                 conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","user","password");
         Statement st=conn.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("Select * from student where rollno="+rollno);
        int c=0;
        while(rs.next()){
      System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"   "+rs.getString(3)+"                "+rs.getString(4));
        c++;
                     } 
         if(c>0)
              {
                 System.out.println("success");
               return("success");
               } 
              conn.close();
                 throw new Exception("record not found");

           }catch(Exception e){
 System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  return("no record found"); 
         }
   }
 }
```

Comment: use `<%@ page import="find_record.StudentBean"%>` at the top of jsp

Comment: @M.Sharma there is no need to import if fully qualified class name is used.

Comment: Check whether class file is created or not. Clean the project and start the server again.

Comment: both the options done but still not  working

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295496/what-is-a-javabean-exactly) which describes how to create a JavaBean.  Your classes must implement Serializable in order for it to be a JavaBean (and have a serialVersionUID assigned).  This allows the bean to be "flattened" and reconstructed where necessary.

Let me know if this doesn't solve the problem entirely.  You also need to make sure that bean is getting placed in the session through the use of a servlet (or scriptlet in the JSP page).

**Above did not solve it.**

Try this:

```
<jsp:useBean id="findbean" class="find_record.StudentBean" scope="session">
    <jsp:setProperty name="findbean" property="rollno"/>
</jsp:useBean>
```

Comment: There is no need to serialize it. that's not an issue. Have you tested the code before posting your answer?

Comment: yes tested and error which is coming is also posted :Student.jsp:1:1: Needed class "find_record.StudentBean" is not found.
^
Student.jsp:4:34: The bean type "find_record.StudentBean" was not found.
<jsp:useBean id="findbean" class="find_record.StudentBean" scope="session" />
                             ^-----------------------^
Student.jsp:5:23: This bean name does not exist.
<jsp:setProperty name="findbean" property="rollno" />

Comment: I added an addendum to the above post with another thing to try.  If you are instantiating the bean using the useBean property, it is likely that you need to place the setProperty between the opening and closing tags of useBean.

Comment: actually i have done this before but was not working

Comment: I am creating a project on my computer.  I'll see if I can get it working.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can tell about your code is that you should not end the IF sentence with ";", or event left it without brackets... Your code as it is, I was not able to run it, but this way I could, try this:

```
<%
    String status = findbean.findRecord();
    if (status.equals("success")) {
%>
<jsp:include page="Success.jsp" />
<% } else { %>
<jsp:include page="Error.jsp" />
<% } %>
```

For everything else, you are doing it ok for the first times. Good luck!