# insert checked item from a listview into Database

Tags: android, database, listview, checkbox, android-sqlite

I am developing an application that shows the user a listView of the applications founded in his device. Each row of the ListView contain a checkBox and the icon of the app. this listView appear in alert dialog .I want to save the checked item into the database when the user click the positive button in the alert dialog. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Make a Bean class for packages add it to an arrayList while clicked on checkBox and Insert it into DB while tapping on positive button of Alert Dialog.

Comment: what do you mean by Bean Class?

Comment: The class which consists of all getter setter methods 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295496/what-is-a-javabean-exactly

Comment: I added the Bean class but how to make the relation between them ?

Comment: Refer this http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/

create an Object and set data to it ...