# Swift: The proper way to initialize model class with a lot of properties

Tags: swift, design-patterns, initialization, option-type

How do you initialize your classes/structs with a lot of properties?

This question could probably be asked without Swift context but Swift brings a flavour to it, so I add Swift tag in headline and tags.

Let's say you have a `User` class with 20 properties. Most of them should not be nil or empty. Let's assume these properties are not interdependent. Let's assume that 33% of it should be constant (`let`) by the logic of the class. Let's assume that at least 65% of them do not have meaningful default values. How would you design this class and initialize an instance of it?

So far I have few thoughts but none of it seems to be completely satisfactory to me:

- put all of the properties linearly in the class and make huge init method:

  ```
  class User {
      // there is 20 properties like that
      let id : String
      let username : String
      let email : String
      ...
      var lastLoginDate : Date
      var lastPlayDate : Date

      // then HUUUUGE init
      init(id: String, 
           username: String,
           ...
           lastPlayDate: Date) {
      }
  }
  ```
- try to group properties into sub types and deal with smaller inits separately

  ```
  class User {
      struct ID {
          let id : String
          let username : String
          let email : String
      }
      struct Activity {
          var lastLoginDate : Date
          var lastPlayDate : Date 
      }
      let id : ID
      ...
      var lastActivity : Activity

      // then not so huge init
      init(id: ID, 
           ...
           lastActivity: Activity) {
      }
  }
  ```
- another solution is to break requirements a bit: either declare some of the properties optional and set values after init or declare dummy default values and set normal values after init, which conceptually seems to be the same

  ```
  class User {
      // there is 20 properties like that
      let id : String
      let username : String
      let email : String
      ...
      var lastLoginDate : Date?
      var lastPlayDate : Date?

      // then not so huge init
      init(id: String, 
           username: String,
           email: String) {
      }
  }

  // In other code 
  var user = User(id: "1", username: "user", email: "user@example.com"
  user.lastLoginDate = Date()
  ```

Is there a nice paradigm/pattern how to deal with such situations?

Comment: You can use the Builder pattern: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33106041/how-do-i-initialize-classes-with-lots-of-fields-in-an-elegant-way

Comment: No good options =/.  I like .net's solution which is to provide built in initializer.  looks something like this: className{prop1=1,prop2=2}.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the builder pattern.

## Example

```
class DeathStarBuilder {

    var x: Double?
    var y: Double?
    var z: Double?

    typealias BuilderClosure = (DeathStarBuilder) -> ()

    init(buildClosure: BuilderClosure) {
        buildClosure(self)
    }
}

struct DeathStar : CustomStringConvertible {

    let x: Double
    let y: Double
    let z: Double

    init?(builder: DeathStarBuilder) {

        if let x = builder.x, let y = builder.y, let z = builder.z {
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.z = z
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    var description:String {
        return "Death Star at (x:\(x) y:\(y) z:\(z))"
    }
}

let empire = DeathStarBuilder { builder in
    builder.x = 0.1
    builder.y = 0.2
    builder.z = 0.3
}

let deathStar = DeathStar(builder:empire)
```

Example taken from here: https://github.com/ochococo/Design-Patterns-In-Swift

If you are looking for a bit more Java like solution, you can try something like this.

## Alternative Example

```
final class NutritionFacts {
    private let servingSize: Int
    private let servings: Int
    private let calories: Int
    private let fat: Int
    private let sodium: Int
    private let carbs: Int
 
    init(builder: Builder) {
        servingSize = builder.servingSize
        servings = builder.servings
        calories = builder.calories
        fat = builder.fat
        sodium = builder.sodium
        carbs = builder.carbs
    }
 
    class Builder {
        let servingSize: Int
        let servings: Int
 
        private(set) var calories = 0
        private(set) var fat = 0
        private(set) var carbs = 0
        private(set) var sodium = 0
 
        init(servingSize: Int, servings: Int) {
            self.servingSize = servingSize
            self.servings = servings
        }
 
        func calories(value: Int) -> Builder {
            calories = value
            return self
        }
 
        func fat(value: Int) -> Builder {
            fat = value
            return self
        }
 
        func carbs(value: Int) -> Builder {
            carbs = value
            return self
        }
 
        func sodium(value: Int) -> Builder {
            sodium = value
            return self
        }
 
        func build() -> NutritionFacts {
            return NutritionFacts(builder: self)
        }
    }
}
 
let facts = NutritionFacts.Builder(servingSize: 10, servings: 1)
    .calories(value: 20)
    .carbs(value: 2)
    .fat(value: 5)
    .build()
```

Example taken from: http://ctarda.com/2017/09/elegant-swift-default-parameters-vs-the-builder-pattern