# how to de serialize a setter less property using Jackson in Java

Tags: jackson

I am using Spring boot web service, @requestbody.While converting JSON to Java Object throwing error message as "Problem deserializing 'setterless' property"

my POJO is like this.

```
Class test 
{
  private List<AdminRequest> _AdminRequestSet;
  public void addAdminRequest(AdminRequest param)
   {
      if (_AdminRequestSet == null)
      {
         _AdminRequestSet = new Vector<AdminRequest>();
      }
      this._AdminRequestSet.add(param);
   }
   public void removeAdminRequest(AdminRequest param)
   {
      this._AdminRequestSet.remove(param);
   }
   public List<AdminRequest> getAdminRequestSet()
   {
      return this._AdminRequestSet;
   }
   public void clearAdminRequest()
   {
      if (_AdminRequestSet == null)
      {
         return;
      }
      _AdminRequestSet.clear();
   }   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `test` is not [Java bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295496/what-is-a-javabean-exactly) conform. The name of the field `_AdminRequestSet` does not correspond to the getter `getAdminRequestSet`. Jackson supports the serialization without setters, but it must be possible to map from the property name in the json to a field in the target class.

For example we have this json:

`{"adminRequestSet": [{"id":1},{"id":2}]}`

Jackson is able to find the getter `getAdminRequestSet` in class `test`, which corresponds to the property `adminRequestSet` in the json. But there is no setter `setAdminRequestSet` and no field `adminRequestSet` in the class `test`.

Now you have different options. Here a list of common solutions:

**Option 1:**
rename the field `_AdminRequestSet` to `adminRequestSet` (so that class test is java bean conform)

**Option 2:**
use an [annotation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations) to specify the property name for a field

```java
@JsonProperty("adminRequestSet")
private List<AdminRequest> _AdminRequestSet;
```

**Option 3:**
If you are not able to change the class `test`, you could use [Jackson MixIns](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations)

```java
abstract class testMixIn {
    @JsonProperty("adminRequestSet") 
    private List<AdminRequest> _AdminRequestSet;
}

//register testMixin for class test
objMapper.addMixIn(test.class, testMixIn.class);
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response. Your answers solved my problem.

Comment: You are welcome, if it works for you, you could mark the answer as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

**Option 4:** Remove unnecessary getter/setter.

Consider this situation:

```
@JsonProperty("data")
private List<AdminRequest> _AdminRequestSet;

public List<AdminRequest> getAdminRequestSet()
{
  return _AdminRequestSet;
}
```

The problem is that, Jackson tried to match the getter/setter pattern on the member, adminRequestSet, but it can't find the data member.  Hence the exception.

Two things you need to consider:

1. Do you actually need to getAdminRequestSet() method?  If so, annotate it with @JsonIgnore.  Let the @JsonProperty("data") to generate the list as "data".
2. Search usage to determine whether you need the getXXX() method.  Remove it if you don't need it.  You don't even have to annotate with @JsonIgnore.