# How can I convert a custom Java class to a Spark Dataset

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset

I can't figure out a way to convert a List of Test objects to a Dataset in Spark
This is my class:

```
public class Test {
    public String a;
    public String b;
    public Test(String a, String b){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public List getList(){
        List l = new ArrayList();
        l.add(this.a);
        l.add(this.b);

        return l;
    }
}
```

Comment: `code` Test t = new Test("1", "Test");
      Test tt = new Test("11", "Test2");
      List<Test> tl = new ArrayList();
      tl.add(t);
      tl.add(tt); 
Dataset<Row> ds = spark.createDataFrame(tl, Test.class);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code in the comments to create a DataFrame is correct. However, there is a problem with the way you define `Test`. You can create DataFrames using your code only from Java Beans. Your `Test` class is not a [Java Bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295496/what-is-a-javabean-exactly). Once you fix that, you can use the following code to create a DataFrame:

```
Dataset<Row> dataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(listOfTestClasses, Test.class);
```

and these lines to create a typed Dataset:

```
Encoder<Test> encoder = Encoders.bean(Test.class);
Dataset<Test> dataset = spark.createDataset(listOfTestClasses, encoder);
```

Comment: By default the encoder sorts the variables alphabetically for creating columns in my dataset. How can I change the default order Test class?

Comment: what is listOfTestClasses here? List<Test> listOfTestClasses ? If it's then it is not working for me :(