# what does a folder named Bean mean in Android?

Tags: android, structure, project

I've seen an Android project structure in the image below. What does "Bean" mean in this structure? or Why does that folder name "Bean"?

[image]

Comment: its a package name my friend

Comment: @NileshRathod: do you understand my question clearly?

Comment: bean means your getter() and setter() method

Comment: This has nothing to do with android `reastBean` is just package . And the word `bean` can be resemble to `POJO` of java.

Comment: @duyhoang yes i have read and understand your question clearly

Comment: @NileshRathod: that folder is used to contain model classes when using Retrofit to get data (Json format) from a webservice

Comment: @duyhoang Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295496/what-is-a-javabean-exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Bean` in java  is basically a single class encapsulate many objects into a single object and there properties can be manipulated by using `getter` and `setter` method.We also call it model class. The below code snippet is an example of bean class.

```
    public class Book implements Serializable{
        private String isbn;
        private String title;
        private String author;
        private String publisher;
        private int pages;
        /**
         * Default constructor
         */
        public Book() {
            this.isbn = "";
            this.title = "";
            this.author = "";
            this.publisher = "";
            this.pages = 0;
        }
        public String getIsbn() {
            return isbn;
        }
        public void setIsbn(final String isbn) {
            this.isbn = isbn;
        }
        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }
        public void setTitle(final String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }
        public String getAuthor() {
            return author;
        }
        public void setAuthor(final String author) {
            this.author = author;
        }
        public String getPublisher() {
            return publisher;
        }
        public void setPublisher(final String publisher) {
            this.publisher = publisher;
        }
        public int getPages() {
            return pages;
        }
        public void setPages(final int pages) {
            this.pages = pages;
 }
}
```

In your case i think the package you pointed contained all the bean classes