# Are "representations" and "beans" the same in the context of Spring RESTful services

Tags: spring, rest

I am getting acquainted to Spring and its ecosystem. Working with Spring RESTful services, I came across `representations`.

```
{"id":1,"content":"Hello, World!"}
```

*A simple representation*

Working in a Java code base, I am trying to understand the difference between **representations** and **beans**.

Reading Spring's introduction to RESTful WebServices ([link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)), I understand that representations are input/output of a RESTful Service Endpoint (JSON in the above example) which is very similar to a java bean. However, *Java Bean* is a standard ([SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3295517/1799502)).

Most, if not all, introduction to REST articles use the term *representation* without defining it. ([spring's introduction to rest](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/), [restful architecutre 101](https://dzone.com/articles/restful-architecture-101), etc). The best definition I found so far ([reference](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_2)) states that;

> A representation is a sequence of bytes, plus representation metadata to describe those bytes. Other commonly used but less precise names for a representation include: document, file, and HTTP message entity, instance, or variant.

Although it sounds like a complex datamodel, it can be broken down to a Java bean, so to reiterate my question, are **representations** and **beans** essentially the same thing especially in the context of Spring RESTful Services?

Answer (score 1):

Don't think they essentially refer to the same concept.

Representation in RESTful API just mean the response formats .Let 's say an API supports returning JSON , XML and plaintext , we say the API response has 3 representations. Which representations (JSON , XML or plaintext) will be returned depending on the `Accept` request header.

During the implementation , we normally use a JavaBean/POJO to represent the response. By using some library such as Jackson , the same JavaBean/POJO can be converted to different representations such as JSON and XML.