# How to find if at least one field is null in a DTO

Tags: java, spring-batch, dto

I work on a Batch with Spring-Batch.
In a processor I have to handle a DTO with approximately twenty fields.

Functionally, if no field is empty I have nothing to do.
So I would like to find out in first place, if no field is empty.

But I don't really want to do an "if" with twenty

```java
DTO.getValue1 != null && DTO.getValue2 != null [...]
```

I wonder if there will not be a cleaner way to do that ?

thx in advance.

Comment: Change the DTO to expose a collection of its fields (some DTOs do this automatically)?

Comment: If your DTO adheres to JavaBeans specifications check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295496/what-is-a-javabean-exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection for validation purposes. Define an isNull method in the DTO to check for null fields.

```
public boolean isNull() {
        Field fields[] = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field f : fields) {
            try {
                Object value = f.get(this);
                if (value != null) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
        return true;

    }
```

Comment: Yeah thx
functionnaly is more:
```java
if (value == null) {
                    return false;
}
```
But I have my answer.