# How do you mock inputs to methods for testing in Python?

Tags: python, oop, mocking

I am looking to test some code in Python - specifically class methods.

I have a class that looks like

```
class BigBoyClass:
   def __init__(self, ...{configuration objects}...):
       ...{expensive init}...
       self.init_attr1 = ...
       self.init_attr2 = ...

   def method1(self):
      self.new_attr1 = ...
      self.new_attr2 = ...
```

To test `method1` I want to pass it a "`self`" with particular values in `init_attr1` and `init_attr2`

So far I've been doing:

```
class DummyContainer:
    def __init__(self):
       pass

c = DummyContainer()
c.init_attr1 = {v1}
c.init_attr2 = {v2}

BigBoyClass.method1(c)

assert c.new_attr1 == {v3}
assert c.new_attr2 == {v4}
```

But I get a feeling I'm re-inventing the wheel here. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed. If you can refactor the `BigBoyClass.__init__` method, you can do better than mocks !

Based on your example, here is my initial situation :

```py
class BigBoyClass:
   def __init__(self, big_number: int):
       sum(range(big_number))  # something slow
       self.init_attr1 = big_number  # whatever
       self.init_attr2 = big_number + 1  # whatever

   def method1(self):
      self.new_attr1 = 4  # whatever
      self.new_attr2 = 5  # whatever


def test_method1():
    # given
    instance = BigBoyClass(10**9)  # takes a few seconds on my computer

    # when
    instance.method1()

    # then
    assert (instance.new_attr1 == 4) and (instance.new_attr2 == 5)
```

What I want is a **dumb** `__init__` : it is given parameters, it just sets them to the corresponding `self` fields. The complex part is moved to a [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) that will handle the complex part.

```py
class BigBoyClass:
    def __init__(self, attr1: int, attr2: int):
        # removed the slow part here
        self.init_attr1 = attr1
        self.init_attr2 = attr2

    def method1(self):
        self.new_attr1 = 4  # whatever
        self.new_attr2 = 5  # whatever

    @classmethod
    def init_with_config_object(cls, big_number: int):
        sum(range(big_number))  # something slow
        return cls(big_number, big_number+1)


def test_method1():
    # given
    instance = BigBoyClass(10**9, 10**9+1)  # lightning-fast !

    # when
    instance.method1()

    # then
    assert (instance.new_attr1 == 4) and (instance.new_attr2 == 5)
```

I did not change my test at all, but because I changed the `__init__` signature, now I have to adapt all the other existing instantiations of the `BigBoy` class, to call the `init_with_config_object` instead of just the class itself.

What you gain from doing that :

- no need to mock, so it's easier to write tests
- no mocks, so that you don't have to maintain them when your actual class change
- you can check separately that the configuration initializes correctly, and that the method does what expected
- you can add other classmethods if you need to be able to instantiate the same class but in different ways
- if providing the values for the `init_attr` of your object is complex, you can create *test factories* : functions that will handle that for you, using a direct call to `__init__` anyway

I don't know if this technique has a name, but it looks a bit like a ["java beans"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295496/what-is-a-javabean-exactly) because it provides the way to be constructed in any way, without restrictions on signatures/protocols.